# Singular or plural 'electrical loads'

Tags: grammatical-number

I have the following sentence:

"The methods can be used with every kind of flexible electrical **loads** "

Should load be in singular or plural?By flexible electrical loads I am referring to e.g. electric vehicles, heat pumps, dishwashers

Comment: Consider another example: "We employ every kind of cook." The noun **cook** is generally a countable noun, yet it is used in the singular here.

Comment: Generally, "kind of" (in this sense) expects a singular noun.

Comment: "every kind of load" or "all possible loads"

Comment: Compare the simpler but parallel example 'every kind of car' and 'every kind of cars'. One is ungrammatical.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Consider another example: "We employ every kind of cook." The noun **cook** is generally a countable noun, yet it is used in the singular here.

Weather Vane

> Generally, "kind of" (in this sense) expects a singular noun.

Hot Licks

> "every kind of load" or "all possible loads"

shogun

> Compare the simpler but parallel example 'every kind of car' and 'every kind of cars'. One is ungrammatical.

Edwin Ashworth

Comment: Thanks for your answer CJ Dennis. What about the phrase 'every type of flexible electrical loads'. Shall 'loads' be used in plural or singular 'load' here?

Comment: The important word is "every". It takes a singular noun. It doesn't matter whether the noun is "kind" or "type".

Comment: Thanks CJ for your answer. What about 'all types of...'. I gues this is the same, right?

Comment: @PeterBe Yes, "all" takes a plural noun, e.g. "kinds" or "types".